# Convert English words to integers

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash

I am looking for an algorithm that can convert English words to unique integers. There are about 500000 words in English dictionary, I want to compare integers, not strings, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string> 

int convert_word_to_int(const std::string& word) {
    // some algorithm that I am looking for
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s1 = "wonderful";
    std::string s2 = "flower";
    std::string s3 = "car";

    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(convert_word_to_int(s1));
    v.push_back(convert_word_to_int(s2));
    v.push_back(convert_word_to_int(s3));

    std::string word = "car";
    int number = convert_word_to_int(word);
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        if (number == v[i]) {
            std::cout << "The word is exists" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "The word is not exists" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: search for stl map

Comment: i think that there is some hashing algoorithm for my problem, the stl map is not that i am looking for

Comment: And why don't you want to compare strings?

Comment: So you want a data-free function which only depends on the one word passed, not on the history of the running program? Even if you can find something that avoids collisions for your set of English dictionary words, there will be collisions with non-word strings (maybe for example `convert_word_to_int("car") == convert_word_to_int("hbwiz")`); is that okay?

Comment: because comparing integers is even faster than comparing strings

Comment: Meh. The simple thing is to just number your strings. Failing that, just pick a well-established hash function. Sort your list, either way. If you don't bother sorting, the difference between a string comparison and integer comparison won't save you. Seems a bit XY to my.

Comment: @aschepler, i have a file, there is about 500 000 English words written line by line, i want just all that words convert to UNIQUE integers using some algorithm, maybe hashing algorithm, maybe something else, after converting, i will have array of hashed words, my program input is a sentence, and i want to know which word exists in my dictionary which not

Comment: @sweenish, yeah, i also think about sorting after converting to integers, and i am looking for a hashing algorithm

Comment: Very difficult just to find a hash which doesn't have any collisions for that many words: you'd be working against the birthday problem. If the input can contain non-words, practically impossible. There are more sequences of 7 lowercase Latin letters than there are values of 32-bit integer.

Comment: if some word in input sentence doesn't exist in my dictionary, i just skip the word

Comment: So you have a way to test if a string is a dictionary word without this hash function? And the data or algorithm involved in that can't give some useful index?

Comment: If the words are unique then treat them as numbers in base 26, or base 52 if capitalization is significant.  To include digits use base 36 or base 62.

Comment: @aschepler, no after converting to integers, i will search in array of integers, not in array of strings

Comment: my friend said that "open address hashing" algorithm can help me, do you know about it?

Comment: Hashes have hash collisions. You can't avoid the fact that there will sometimes be inputs where `a != b` but `f(a) == f(b)`. Hashes can be useful to speed up some algorithms, but never by using hash values alone. Different hash values mean different inputs, but if hash values match, the algorithm must then check whether the actual values match too.

Comment: If you're reading them from a file, just assign a number and increment as you go. Or use a map as suggested. There is no reason to over-complicate this.

Comment: Or use `std::unordered_set<std::string>`, which does use `std::hash<std::string>` to bin its values into buckets.

Comment: @aschepler, yeah i think so, where i can find how unordered set hases? because i want to store hashed integers in different array

Comment: You can use `std::hash<std::string>()(word)` directly, if that's what you mean.

Comment: If you are "searching a list" through a loop, you are losing all of the efficiency of using integers instead of strings.

Comment: Use rolling hash.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem to me. What is the real problem you're trying to solve here, that makes you think you need to optimize your string comparisons?